# open fallback url when application is not installed using intent

Tags: android-intent

I have used intent for same, but its only supported  in mozilla & chrome

code:

```
   <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;=package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

Where as in opera it opens app , but when app is not present then it should open specified `fallback url` but it's not working for `opera mini`& `opera`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @php-rider does this still work in firefox? I am not able open `intent://` urls successfully in **firefox** if i specify `S.browser_fallback_url` and app is already installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open using one form using iframe  & other one is using href link.

Comment: can you explain more porperly i didn't understand what you meant please , I am also stuck on the same problem